# Cocoa: programmatically detect frontmost floating windows

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, cocoa

I'm writing a Mac app that change its behavior depending on the frontmost app. I subscribed to `NSWorkspaceDidActivateApplicationNotification` and can easily know which app is active at the moment. However, there's no such notifications for some floating panels like the ones of Spotlight, Alfred or the character picker. As I understand, they aren't really *active* because they use the `NSNonactivatingPanelMask` style mask, but they still can be focused.

Is there any way I could know when one of those is frontmost and focused and get the bundle id (or something similar) of their parent application?

Comment: This is a good question and a very difficult problem. One place to look at may be `NSAccessibilityFocusedWindowChangedNotification` and the `AXObserverAddNotification` function...

Comment: As far as I understand, `AXObserver`s are specific to one application. I should thus a list of apps I want to monitor, somehow find their PID, and then observe them. I will try out, though, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Did you figure out a proper solution to this? Did listing apps, grabbing their PIDs, and observing them work for you?

Comment: Looks like that is a valid solution to this problem - get pids for all the apps you want, and use ```AXObserver``` and ```AXObserverAddNotification``` to get notifications on them. Note that these types of floating panels probably won't have a "focused window", so you'll most likely need to use ```NSAccessibilityFocusedUIElementChangedNotification```.

Comment: I am from 2023, still having same problem. no great way to deal with this. Ah. Apple :)